# Determining precisely where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Inspired by the exponential series, I'm curious about where exactly the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ converges.

I calculated
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/n}}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(n)/n}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n}=e^0=1.
$$
So the radius of convergence is $1$, so the series converges on all $z$ inside $S^1$. But is there a way to tell for which $z$ on the unit circle the series converges? I know it converges for $z=-1$, but diverges for $z=1$, but I don't know about the rest of the circle. For what other $z$ does this series converge? Thanks.

Comment: From the Wikipedia articles on the Mercator series (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) and Abel's Test (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test#Abel.27s_test_in_complex_analysis), it converges everywhere on the circle _but_ $z=1$.

Comment: Thanks @StevenStadnicki. I see how Abel's test applies here now, but I don't see how the article on the Mercator series is relevant. What exactly are you using in that article?

Comment: I think this would be a good opportunity to take a look at [summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts).

Comment: @Hobbie Specifically, the bit under 'Complex series' where it describes where the series converges and how Abel's test gets you there. :-)  Note that since the series they gave there is $f(z) = \ln(1+z)$, your series is $-f(-z) = -\ln(1-z) = \ln(\frac{1}{1-z})$.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Fix $z$ in the unit circle, i.e. $|z|=1$. We want to apply [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_test): if $\{a_n\}$ are real numbers and $\{b_n\}$ complex numbers such that:

1. $a_1\geq a_2\geq\cdots$
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$
3. There exists $M>0$ such that $\left|\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n\right|\leq M$ for every $N\in\mathbb{N}$;

then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ converges. Here $a_n=1/n$, $b_n=z^n$. The first two conditions are clearly satisfied, and for the third one:
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^Nz^{ n }\right|=\left|\frac{z-z^{N+1}}{1-z}\right|\leq\frac{2}{|1-z|}
$$
for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$. 
This shows that the third condition is satisfied for every $z\ne1$ in the circle.

In conclusion, the series converges for every $z$ with $|z|\leq1$ other than $z=1$, and it diverges for $|z|>1$.

Comment: Can you explain this step: $|\sum_{n=1}^Nz^{ n }| = |\frac{z-z^{N+1}}{1-z}|$ ?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Comment: Yeah, but where do you get that additional $z$ in the nominator from? By the formula you linked it should be $|\frac{1-z^{N+1}}{1-z}|$, no?

Comment: If you start the sum from $0$, yes.

Answer (score 10):

The following theorem on power series is due to E. Picard:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers.
>
> If the sequence $(a_n)$ is nonnegative, decreases and tends to zero when $n\to \infty$, then the complex power series $\sum a_n\ z^n$ converges in the closed unit disc $\overline{D}(0;1)$ with the only possible exception of the point $1$.

The proof of Picard's theorem relies on *Abel's summation by parts formula*, as far as I remember.

Now, the coefficients of your series, i.e. $a_n=1/n$, satisfy the assumptions of Picard's theorem, hence your series converges at least in $\overline{D}(0;1)\setminus \{1\}$; on the other hand, the series diverges when $z=1$ (for it becomes the *harmonic series*).

Therefore the convergence set of $\sum 1/n\ z^n$ is $\overline{D}(0;1)\setminus \{1\}$.

Answer (score -2):

Even though the 1st answer is the more easy and appropriate here is a more analytic one. $\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{z^n}{n} =\frac{z}{1-z} $$\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} [\frac{1-z^n}{n(n+1)} + \frac{1-z^k}{k}]$

(we can prove that with induction till k).

We can also see that

$0 \leqslant | \frac{1-z^k}{k}|\leqslant \frac{2}{k}\rightarrow 0$ for k$\rightarrow$$\infty$

also,

$0 \leqslant |\frac{1-z^n}{n(n+1)}|\leqslant \frac{2}{n(n+1)} $

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n(n+1)}$ converges so

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$ converges as well