# Closed form of series $z^n/n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$. In other question is answered [precisely where $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/118686/622884).

I have been looking for an expression of
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$$
without infinite sum. I mean, a closed expression of this simple hypergeometric sum, similar to, for example,
$$\forall |z|<1 , \ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}.$$
Is there any closed form of the hypergeometric series $z^n/n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum is $-\log(1-z)$, where $\log$ is the main logarithm.

Comment: Can you please explain why or give some reference?

Comment: Consider the function $z\mapsto-\log(1-z)$. Obviosuly, it maps $0$ into $0$. And if you differentiate it, you get $\frac1{1-z}=1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots$.

Comment: Integrate both sides of the equality$$\frac1{1-z}=1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots$$and you get that$$-\log(1-z)=z+\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^3}3+\frac{z^4}4+\cdots$$