# Sum the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

The problem asks to sum it in its circle of convergence.

It's radius of convergence is $R=lim_{n \to \infty} \left|{\frac{\frac{1}{2n+1}}{\frac{1}{2n+2}}}\right|$=1. And when $\left|z\right|=1$ it diverges by the Limit Comparison Test with $1/n$. So its circle of convergence is $\left|z\right|<1$, id est, $z \in D(0,1)$.

We have that
$$ 
 \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n} \right)' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n-1} = -1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n} = -1 + \frac{1}{1-z}
$$
when $\left|z\right|<1$, so doing the integration we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n} = \int \left(-1 + \frac{1}{1-z}\right)dz=-z-\log(1-z)+C
$$
But the thing is, ¿what is the value of that C?

Comment: Hint: Take $z=0$ on both sides.

Comment: Thank you Linding, now I see.

Comment: There is a mistake in the first line of your derivation. The first term ($-1$) should not be there.

Comment: @Fabian why not? isn't it necessary to supply the $z^0=1$ that we add to the series?

Comment: @baristocrona you are not adding $1$ to the series. You are only reindexing it. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n-1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^m$, by the substitution $m=n-1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closed form of series $z^n/n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253366/closed-form-of-series-zn-n) Or some other post of [this list](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7Bz%5En%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1)?

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks for the explanation.