# Does $\operatorname{P.V.} \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n z^n} = \infty$ for all $z$ in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers

Let $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ and take $z^n = e^{n\operatorname{Log z}}$ where $\operatorname{Log}$ is the principal branch of $\log$. We denote the positive real infinity as $+\infty$ and the complex infinity as $\infty$.

Define
$$\operatorname{P.V.} \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n z^n} = \lim_N \left(\frac{N}{z^{\frac{1}{N}}} + \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n z^n}\right)$$
We wish to find out if $$\operatorname{P.V.} \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n z^n} = \infty$$
In other words, does $$\frac{1}{\frac{N}{z^{\frac{1}{N}}} + \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n z^n}} \to 0$$ as $N \to +\infty$?

---

We know $$\lim_N \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n z^n} = -\operatorname{Log}\left(1 - \frac{1}{z}\right)$$ for $|z| > 1$ by Taylor series expansion.

Hence for a fixed $z$, $\left(\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n z^n}\right)$ converges to a complex constant and $\left(z^{\frac{1}{N}}\right) \to 1$ as $N \to +\infty$. Thus we can conclude that $$\lim_N \left(\frac{N}{z^{\frac{1}{N}}} + \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n z^n}\right) = \infty$$ for $|z| > 1$.

In fact, the same argument works when $|z| = 1$ and $z \neq 1$, because by [Determining precisely where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118686/determining-precisely-where-sum-n-1-infty-fracznn-converges), $\left(\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n z^n}\right)$ converges to a complex constant when $|z| = 1$ and $z \neq 1$.

For z = 1, $\left(\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n z^n}\right)$ is the harmonic series which diverges to $+\infty$ as $N \to +\infty$ and $z^{\frac{1}{N}} = 1$ and hence $$\lim_N \left(\frac{N}{z^{\frac{1}{N}}} + \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n z^n}\right) = \infty$$

How about for $|z| < 1$?

Comment: When you sum up the series as a logarithm, the sum should be an inifnite one not just up to $N$.

Comment: @Gary Fixed, thanks.

Comment: It seems that for fixed $|z|<1$, $z\neq 0$, $\sum_{n = 1}^N {\frac{1}{{nz^n }}}  \sim \frac{1}{{1 - z}}\frac{1}{{Nz^N }}$ as $N\to +\infty$.